How locate a source of knowledge with a spell?
Specific case:

Big Bad's library/laboratory/office inside his headuarters, right after his demise.
Extremely short amount of time (half an hour to hour before other interested parties arrive).
Need to find several different pieces of specific information that is supposed to be there but can be on any kind of medium (books, manuscripts, loose papers, tablets, runework, etc.).

I'm looking for spells that can help me find it all. Important to note:

It's as much about accessing the information as it is about preventing other interested parties from being able to. This means spells Like Legend Lore or Ancestral Memory won't do, even if they were able to provide us with needed information (which, RAW, they mostly cannot).
Most of the information is not a generally accessible one. List of co-conspirators to target, list of true names of outsiders to bind, tomes with ritual spells described in them, etc.

The game plays mostly RAW, bar some complete & utter nonsence left by Paizo so spells like Locate Object won't help much (they either require a specific object in mind or general objects and "find me a book" isn't something that will help at all).

The casting time of the spells commune and contact other plane is 10 min. each. Is that too long to wait? Or have those solutions already been considered and rejected for reasons the question doesn't mention?

I assume you are not willing/able to use wish?

Commune and Contact not even considered because the problem is finding physical objects containing the information, NOT just the information itself.

Wish isn't available yet and not anytime soon.

But you use Commune and CoP to help you find the source of the information, not the information itself.

I think more information is needed about the resources available to the party.

Commune with texts
The Commune with texts spell says:

You quickly absorb the knowledge in the target, which can be any assortment of books, scrolls, or other texts. During the spell’s duration, you can search the texts and immediately find the most relevant information regarding any topic the collection holds, potentially including singling out spellbooks or scrolls containing individual or particular types of spells.

I think this is the closest thing you can get. Its available as a level 4-6 spell to a wide array if classes.
Other spells that could allow you to learn that, like commune, contact other plane or divination are all vague enough in their replies and limited enough in how much you can ask that this will take you days or weeks to triangulate out from many castings, not just a few minutes.
If you do not have access to Commune with Texts, my recommendation is to just instead grab all the documents, or as many of them as you can. Put them in a bag of holding, or just stuff as much as you can into sacks and backpacks, and hide those with nondetection if needed. That way, you make sure the other party won't get their hands on those documents, or at least you maximize your chances they will not, and can go through them later, when you have more time.

I have access to it as god-arcanist. It's absolutely perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you very much!!!
